# Update @Model using jQuery and diffrent controller/function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model

I will try to explain it simply because of It little bit complicated:
I am trying to create a Blockchain wallet, I loaded my view successfully using AccountController. In there I have the wallet balance and everything works great.

But sometimes I want to transfer money (=change the wallet balance)
My view read the balance using the @Model returned from the AccountController (Account class).

My problem is to update the @Model. From what I did - nothing changed so far.

After posting the recipient address and money to transfer back to the server, right into a different controller using jQuery (pressing a button),
I need to return the @Model to the view with the updated balance, which will be invoked right into the HTML elements that already read it.
In the server, I already have the account instance with the same details.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <label id="ETH-Value">@Model.AccountBalance ETH</label>
  <table>
      .....
      <tr >
         <td style="">
         <input name="RecipientAmountInput" type="number"  required="required" id="RecipientAmountInput" placeholder="Enter Amount" min="0" max=@Model.AccountBalance>
         </td>
         <td ">
            <a style="color:blue;" href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="SendMoneyTransaction()" id="nextButton"><strong>Next></strong></a>
         </td>
       </tr>
  </table>
```

jQuery:

```
  function SendMoneyTransaction()
    { 
        var recipientAddress = $('#RecipientAddressInput').val();
        var tranferValueETH = $('#RecipientAmountInput').val();
        .....
        var url = "/SendDepositETH/SendMoney";
        $.post(url, { AddressTo: recipientAddress, Amount: tranferValueETH }, function (data) 
        {
          //The post is working
            ...
         })
```

C# (server):

```
 ...
 public class SendDepositETHController : Controller
 {
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendMoney(String AddressTo, String Amount)
    {
        double amountToSend = Convert.ToDouble(Amount);
        Account transferFrom = AccountController.myAccount;
        transferFrom.AccountBalance = amountToSend;  //for example
        return View(transferFrom);
    }

  }
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller, you can: return transferFrom; and change IActionResult to Account.
In View,

```
 $.post(url, { AddressTo: recipientAddress, Amount: tranferValueETH }, function (data) 
        {
          //The post is working
          // Something like this
            $("#ETH-Value").val(data.AccountBalance);
         })
```

Comment: I thought about it already, but it will make a mess in my project because I already have the Model which contains the information

Comment: try  return RedirectToAction("YourAction", "YourController", transferFrom);